# Fast selection of elements from a set, based on a property

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, query-optimization

How can I store multiple values of a large set to be able to find them quickly with a lambda expression based on a property with non-unique values?

Sample case (not optimized for performance):

```
class Product
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

IList<Product> products = this.LoadProducts();

var q1 = products.Where(c => c.Title == "Hello"); // 1 product.
var q2 = products.Where(c => c.Title == "Sample"); // 5 products.
var q3 = products.Where(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Title)); // 12 345 products.
```

If title was unique, it would be easy to optimize performance by using `IDictionary` or `HashSet`. But what about the case where the values are not unique?

Comment: A binary search tree sorted on `Title` maybe (if that is the only property you need to find)

Comment: Your last query won't compile. Did you mean `string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Title)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a dictionary of collections of `Product`. Easiest is to use

```
var products = this.LoadProducts().ToLookup(p => p.Title);

var example1 = products["Hello"]; // 1 product
var example2 = products["Sample"]; // 5 products
```

Your third example is a little harder, but you could use [`ApplyResultSelector()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548661.aspx) for that.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the ability to run indexed queries in LINQ. (same as we do in SQL)

There is a library called i4o which apparently can solve your problem:

http://i4o.codeplex.com/

from their website:

> i4o (index for objects) is the first class library that extends LINQ
>   to allow you to put indexes on your objects. Using i4o, the speed of
>   LINQ operations are often over one thousand times faster than without
>   i4o.
>
> i4o works by allowing the developer to specify an
>   IndexSpecification for any class, and then using the
>   IndexableCollection to implement a collection of that class that
>   will use the index specification, rather than sequential search, when
>   doing LINQ operations that can benefit from indexing.

also the following provides an example of how to use i4o:

http://www.hookedonlinq.com/i4o.ashx

Make it short you need to:

1. Add [Indexable()] attribute to your "Title" property
2. Use IndexableCollection<Product> as your data source.
3. From this point, any linq query that uses an indexable field will use the index rather than doing a sequential search, resulting in order of magnituide performance increases for queries using the index.

Comment: I haven't yet used it in a production yet, but looking forward to do so.